# Ghostscript loses font while extracting the page from PDF

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I split PDF into pages with help of usable command line:

```
for G in $(seq 1 $(pdfinfo 47.pdf | sed -n 's/Pages:[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p')) ; do 
   gs \
    -dSAFER \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -dBATCH \
    -dNOPAUSE \
    -dFirstPage=$G \
    -dLastPage=$G \
    -o $G.pdf \
     47.pdf ;
done
```

But some pages appears without text (Graphics are still present)

So, I have tried to extract embedded font from PDF:

```
gs -q -dNODISPLAY extractFonts.ps -c "(47.pdf) extractFonts quit"
```

These fonts I have installed in system Fonts folder.

After that, I have repeat splitting and no changes were happened.

How-to be sure that pages will be extracting correctly, I have no idea now.

Comment: Extracting fonts from a PDF to re-use them the way you do will usually not work as you expect. Most PDF-embedded fonts are *subsets only* (not the full font with all glyphs) and they'll have a different name after extraction (usually with a 6-letter-prefix to the original name), and they'll have a non-standard encoding too.... All of which makes it impossible to re-use the extracted font corpse in a reliable way.

Answer (score 2):

Ghostscript and pdfwrite are not actually intended for the purpose of splitting PDF files up, there are other tools which will probably work better, why not try pdftk ?

If you really want to use Ghostscript then I would advise you to get hold of the latest bleeding-edge code from the Git repository, in that code the pdfwrite device will accept an output file name containing a '%d' and will write one file per page.

Beyond that, it seems most likely to me that you are simply experiencing a bug, rather than 'losing the font', if the font was missing the text would still be ther but in a differnt font. Which version of GS are you using ?

Comment: GPL Ghostscript 9.04 (2011-08-05)

Comment: Well that's 'reasonably' recent, in that its less than a year old. However the current version is 9.05 and the next version will be released in ~2-3 months. I would suggest that you find single page  file which exhibits the problem when passed through pdfwrite, check it with the current version, and if it still exhibits the problem, raise a bug report at http://bugs.ghostscript.com, attach the file and specify the command line to use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KenS: It's good to hear that the *'%d'* goodness will soon arrive in pdfwrite too :-)  Great!